# Tomcat Servlet - is it possible that params get mixed up from different requests?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet that does a DB update/insert - sender and recipient ID. I see that the data in DB seems to be mixed up, and the only inference I can make is that somehow the servlet call I made and what my friend made got mixed up and his ID (as sender) got inserted along with the recipient IDs that I had sent.

Is this even possible ? If so, how do I ensure that each call runs thread-safe and the params don't get mixed up ? Appreciate your help.

```
String senderUserName = request.getHeader(Utils.SNDR_UN_TAG);
String recipientUserNames = request.getHeader(Utils.RCP_UN_LIST_TAG);

con = Utils.getDbConnection();
String updateQry = "UPDATE ofNotifyUserIsOnline " +
               " SET openreq = 'Y' " +
               " WHERE senderusername = ? AND recipientusername = ?";
PreparedStatement psUpdateNotifReq = con.prepareStatement(updateQry);
psUpdateNotifReq.setString(1, senderUserName);
psUpdateNotifReq.setString(2, listRecipientUserNames[counter]);
count = psUpdateNotifReq.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Tomcat is fine, but this sort of thing can happen if *your* servlet mixes up parameters from multiple requests.  This is easy to do, because the same instance of your servlet class is used by multiple simultaneous requests.  Beginners will often put request data in servlet class instance fields, which causes problems like this.  Can't give any more specific advice, since you didn't provide any specific information about your servlet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My servlet function is very simple - receives 2 params, senderID and recipientID as request.getHeader(<name>), which I insert into a DB table. But I saw that for a couple of records, though I was the sender, my friend's ID got inserted along with my recipient.

Comment: Actually, I can give some specific advice -- Make a handler class and have your servlet create a new instance of this to handle each request.  Put all of your request-specific fields and processing in there.  The servlet class itself should normally be very small.  Since the handler is only used by one request, you don't have to worry about interactions between requests unless you explicitly share stuff.

Comment: Are you making a new DB connection for each request?  It could be a problem if you aren't, but even if you are there could be problems in your code that we can't see.  When you say "my code only does... ", you are leaving out the buggy part.

Comment: No, I am getting a handle to the DB Connection, leaving it to the DriverManager to decide if it is new or existing. Is that causing the problem ?

Comment: If your servlet is small you should post it

Comment: Have added the code. Please check

Comment: where is con declared?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138468/discussion-between-krishnan-v-s-and-matt-timmermans).